# How to insert the records in child table when records are inserted into parents table in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, etl, ssis-2012, ssis-2008, msbi

I am stuck with a scenario in SSIS. I have two table both maintain the referential integrity means one is parent table and another is child. When I insert the some records in parent table then those new records should be insert into child table.

Please share if you have any idea to implement this in SSIS.

Comment: Are the records to be inserted identical? i.e. you have 5 child records. Do you insert 5 parent records and do they have identical fields? Do you need to preserve a key that is generated in the child record?

Comment: Add some steps to the SSIS package to insert data into the child table after the inserts into the parent table are complete. It's really that easy!

Comment: Can you be more exact about what the challenge is, here?   If you know how to insert records in the parent table, surely you must know how to insert records into a child table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description I take for granted, that you know WHICH child records have to be cretaed for WHICH master record, so I guess there are basiacally two possibilities.

1. All data is known at runtime:

   - Create a dataflow, which populates the master table
   - Cretae a second dataflow, which populates the child table and connect it to the first dataflow via Succeed constraint

But basically this sounds bit too easy - guess you tried this out already? So here comes possibility 2: the parent table creates IDs, which have to be referenced by the child records:

- Again we start with one dataflow in order to populate the master table
- then we add a second dataflow - again attached to the first one via succeed constraint
- in this dataflow we add a lookup, which checks the master table for the corresponding IDs
- This ID is then written to the corresponding column in the child table.